# jQuery Globalize - How to add new calendar pattern

Tags: jquery-globalization

I want to add support for the General Date Time Format to jQuery Globalize as it's the default format for outputting a `DateTime` as a `string` in .NET.

How can I extend an existing culture and add a new calendar pattern? The [GitHub page](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#extend) documents the `addCultureInfo` function but I've been able to get this working with such a deep path:

`calendars > standard > patterns`.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to fiddle with it in the console of the browser, but here it is. Note, the addition is not within the calendars > standard > patterns.

```
Globalize.addCultureInfo("en-US", {
    calendar: {
        patterns: {
            X: 'ddd MMM dd yy'
        }
    } });
```